# Slicing Data Using Criteria in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently working on train.csv of Kaggle's titanic dataset.

[image]

I am a newbie to python. I wanted to create new DataFrame that consists of only female ( ignoring all rows that have females ). I am using following commands, but I am getting error:

[image]

Could anyone of you pls take a look ? I have come across similar question but they have not been helpful in my case...

Thanks,

Ajeet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRy this:

```
df[(df['Sex']=='female')]
```

Answer (score 3):

The parentheses are wrong. Try

```
df[df.Sex == 'female']
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in several ways:

```
df = df[df['columnname'] =='whatever'] # keeps only rows that have that value in that column
df = df[df['columnname'] !='whatever'] # the opposite of before. keeps only those that do not have that value

df = df[df['columnname'].isin('whatever','whatever')] # if you want to use multiple values

df = df[~df['columnname'].isin('whatever','whatever')] # the opposite of before

df = df[df['columnname'] > 5] # works also like this
```